# Blade template not displaying font awesome correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a form with a blade label in it. I have font awesome linked on my website and I would like to include an icon on the label also. However, when I attempt to add it to the label it will only take it literal it will not correctly display the font.

```
{{ Form::label('user', '<i class="fa fa-user"></i> User', ['class' => 'loginTypeSelect']); }}
```

is displaying:

```
<i class="fa fa-user"></i> User
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do that through the Form class - because the class automatically 'escapes' all data passed to it.

You need to write the label manually.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I am trying to get into the habit of using just blade but there always seems like something gets in the way. Example: This...lol thanks!